# Take a filename parse it and perform a SQL lookup, use the lookup value for final filename

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems, helper, file-rename

I wish to take a filename, parse it sans the extension, perform a SQL lookup, and finally use the lookup value for final filename. This is being done on thousands of files and should have a configurable to and from argument for the from directory -> to directory.

I am no PS expert, but I know for certain that some of you are!

Here is what I have scraped together so far but I am about to switch to C# or JS with Node unless I figure it out today. I was not able to get it to work, but here is what I've got piecing some things together:

```
function AssociativeFileRenamer($fromDir, $toDir)
{
    // filename is prodId--IBZ.ext => prodId--IBZ__sku-AJSJSJSJSJ.ext
    $fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include
    $sqlText = "select prodId,sku from tbl where prodId like '%lookupValue%'"; 

    $database = "master"; 
    $server = ".";

    $connection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Data Source=$server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=$database");
    $cmd = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlText, $connection);

    $connection.Open();
    $reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

    $results = @()
    
    while ($reader.Read())
    {
        $row = @{}
    
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++)
        {
            $row[$reader.GetName($i)] = $reader.GetValue($i)
        }
    
        $results += new-object psobject -property $row            
    }
    
    $connection.Close();

    foreach( $i in $results) { 
        Rename-Item $i.FullName ($i.basename.substring(0,$i.BaseName.length-4)+".pdf")
    }
}
```

From the source directory, all of the files are scanned and for each file, split everything before the first underscore, thats the product ID. Use that value to lookup the SKU in the DB and then finally copy a renamed version of the existing file to the "to" directory.

I feel like I am sort of close, but I cant figure out the working concrete example and I only have a moment to spend on this. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help! Also up for any other options which may be easier and do not rely on a paid solution etc.

My plan to aggregate the files would be something like this

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include
```

Comment: I can assist you but I need to understand a sample of your input or lookup file and how are you planning to parse it. Then the rest of the game would be easy.

Comment: As an aside,  instead of ```$i.basename.substring(0,$i.BaseName.length-4)```, which assumes a dot and an extension of 3 characters, you could use ```[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($i.basename)``` which would work for any length extension, including none at all…

Comment: Or even ```[System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($i.basename, “pdf”)```